# Cassandra hang on startup

Tags: amazon-web-services, cassandra

I'm running cassandra 3.0.6 and i'm seeing it hang when i start the cassandra service about 1/4 of the time.  Is anyone else seeing this?  Has anyone else had this problem?

I end up having to restart the system during the startup process which inevitable corrupts the system tables and i have to re-bootstrap the node....

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

running cassandra, ubuntu 14.04, AWS (c4.8xlarge)

### edit for info:

- Not sure where to get logs specific to my problem.  They're not in `log/cassandra/system.log` anyways
- The whole host is hanging, not just cassandra.  After starting cassandra i'm no longer able to ssh into the box. (25% of the time)
- the dataset is about 160GB or 40GB per instance with 3 levels of replication.  and happens independently of the dataset i'm using even if there are no keyspaces allocated to the cluster.

Comment: You'll need to add additional details. 1. Logs from during the hangup 2. Is it just cassandra that's hanging, or the host booting. 3. How large is the data set.  4. Does it happen with any other data (e.g. test/dummy data) or only the data you're working with 5. Is this a single node or is it part of a cluster

Comment: @Gene updated question for clarity.

Comment: If it's hanging on startup the relevant logs will be in `output.log`, not `system.log`